# How to make https request from a lambda function which is in a private VPC?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I currently have a lambda function which is inside a Private VPC because I am using it to access a ElasticCache Redis Cluster. However, I am unable to make https requests because of the private VPC.
I have greated a NAT gateway with one of the subnets but all https requests time out.
Should I be creating a second lambda function? How should I be doing this?

Comment: The nat gateway isn't configured properly

Comment: I did eventually get the subnet sfigured out but it seems like the function is very unreliable. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759823/is-it-food-to-have-private-netwok-calls-as-well-as-public-api-calls-inside-apriv

Answer (score 0):

The configuration should be:

- **NAT Gateway** connected to a **public subnet**
- **AWS Lambda function** connected to a **private subnet**
- Private subnet **Route Table** configured to point to the NAT Gateway for `0.0.0.0/0` destination
- **Security Group** on the Lambda function with "Allow All" Outbound rules

Comment: I did eventually get the subnet sfigured out but it seems like the function is very unreliable. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759823/is-it-food-to-have-private-netwok-calls-as-well-as-public-api-calls-inside-apriv

Answer (score -2):

Adding ip address of the server you are trying make an https to, to the outbound rules of the security group might help. The outgoing request must've been disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).